# Centered square images in css without set dimensions

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make square images from rectangular in css. They also need to be centered.

I've read a lot of questions here, but the answers, good as they might be, always use constant sizes in pixels whereas I need tem to be in percents so the theme can remain responsive.

Basically I need to change this:

[image: original]

into this:

[image: square]

but if the screen is even smaller:

[image: small square]

The main problem here is I cannot predict the screen size. It is designed for mobile, so they can vary.

I was thinking about doing css in php (it's for wordpress so it's possible). I was thinking something like width:50% and use the width as a variable, but if I set the height to be equal to width, it will be 50% as well. Is there a way to, I don't know, convert the width to pixels or something? I'm out of ideas, please help.

Comment: mmm....i think u missed to post things in `into this:` & `square` etc....edit required from your end mate! :)

Comment: images are beautiful....but code will be helpful too :)

Comment: Not possible without js code

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that it is just not possible to change the height relative to the width. So your problem is not the image itself (using overflow: hidden or background-size: cover will do that) but having the square size of your container with dynamic width and then the same height.

A very strange way would be to use a square image (_blank.png with 1px x 1px) and add width: 100% so the height will be the same.

with css:
div{width: 30%;}
img{width: 100%;}

and then add your actual picture as background-image with

background-size: cover;
background-position: center;

Neither performant nor beautiful, but it works.

Comment: that's interesting and mind-blowing 0_0
I'll make sure to test drive that, but I'm afraid I'm not going to be able to use the images uploaded as background, since they need to stay dynamic in wordpress :(

Comment: ok, then include both images as img-tag, the blank.png and your actual picture. the actual picture can then be absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `img{max-width:100% !important; margin:0 auto !important;}` and I think it will help you.

Comment: I think the image will not be square then

Comment: For square you have to use square image. Or you can style in CSS.

Comment: The thing is cannot use square img :(

Comment: Ok. At first use this and let me know, how is it working ? Actually for responsive purpose this should work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
img { width: 80%; }
```

make sure there is no height for img in your css file. Also make sure not to set something like height="500px" width="500px" in your html/php file.

also to be centered just do

```
img { margin: auto; }
```

Comment: But if do use

img {width: 80%;} won't it resize the whole picture?

Comment: that's the problem, because as I mentioned in the original post, the original images are rectangular :(

Comment: There is no limit, unfortunately. The images uploaded via wordpress will be used in a couple of places each, which means the same images will be styled differently in different places, which, in turn, means they uploaders have to have the ability to use rectangular images.

The square ones from the questions are to be used on the front page for mobile version, but if someone uses regular desktop, they will see the images in their original, rectangular form

Answer (score 0):

Nice picture ;)

If you have an image you want centred—but covers—a parent element, using CSS only, then you’ll need two wrappers:

This works only for wide images. Portrait images will just centre themselves within the container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .outer-wrapper {
                position: relative;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .inner-wrapper {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                right: -50%;
            }
            .inner-wrapper img {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                left: -50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer-wrapper">
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <img src="//placehold.it/400x200" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't this mean the image is always 200px heigh and wide?

Comment: that's the problem - they cannot have a fixed width, like 200x200 since they need to resize :(

Comment: Well make `.outer-wrapper` a percentage-based value or similar; the solution should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following css for your image. It won't break the pixels/dimensions for the image.

```
.imageClass img {
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
}
.imageClass img {
 width: auto;
 height: 50%;
}

<img src="image_path" alt="" class="imageClass" />
```